# Where do the static images / pictures saved for the React Native App?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Where do the static images / pictures saved for the React Native App?

Whether the Images are stored on the client side - Mobile App or it will be render from Server?

Answer (score 1):

All assets which you use are saved on the client side. React native bundler saves all images which you required via `require('./image-path')` in native project. You can easily check it by opening some ipa-file with `Show package content`.

[image: ios assets for example]

The same principe for android.
Also, this a reason why you can't use `require('./' + someVarPath 'blabla')`. Bundler just won't understand what should it put into native project.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I will save all Static Assets in server side. If you are using express for you server, you can take a look at [express static](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: it seems like you speak about web-development. Are you sure your answer touches mobile development?

Comment: I agree with @KonstantinYakushin, we will have to put all the static images on the client side.. static images can be icon, png or jpg files.. all these has to be saved on client side ..